# Wide-Sense Stationarity - Can I say this about it?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Every reference I see about WSS stochastic processes states it as a definition, maybe solves a few examples, and moves on without saying much about it conceptually. Let's take the discrete case $\left\{\mathbf{X}_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_0^\infty\right\}$.

Other than the fact that we can examine the power spectrum/cross spectrum and that the cross-correlations are sort of "time-invariant" and it's a function of a single variable, what more intuitive/conceptual things can you say about a WSS process?

Is it fair to say if a $\mathbf{X}$ is WSS, we can argue modeling the data with a Gaussian process is a decent model? What kind of things can we say about modeling just based on WSS?

EDIT:
I have a hunch that modeling thing is a decent assumption, because Dube theorem 3.1 seems to be saying that any mean and covariance pair can be mapped to a Gaussian process (assuming the mean/covariance functions have certain properties, which I think just guarantee they can be generated by at least ONE stochastic process).

Comment: Stationarity and normality are two properties that are about as "independent" as one can imagine. So, unless you provide a decent definition of "decent" in the phrase "a decent model", the question is rather empty.

Comment: @Did I'm finding that a WSS Gaussian process that relates to an arbitrary WSS process has the same parameters as the optimal linear predictor for that arbitrary random process.